# Visual Studio Code Segmentation Fault on Debian

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, debian, glibc, visual-studio-code

I [downloaded](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and extracted VS Code in a Debian x64 VM and tried to run it.  It complained about missing glibc libraries (I have 2.13, it needs 2.15).  I followed [these steps](https://superuser.com/a/795304) to get Ubuntu DEBs.  Using those, VS Code throws a segmentation fault when I run it.  `gdb` tells me:

```
linux_test_for_tracefork: waitpid: unexpected status 11.
```

Why won't Visual Studio Code run for me in my Debian VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Debian 8 fixed this problem.